# Using for loop to build DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am using the following code to make a DataFrame which contains closing prices of two symbols with column heading as their symbol name respectively.

```
symbols=['KEL','PAEL']
start_date = '2016-05-01'
end_date = '2017-03-02'
allocation = 50000


def data(symbol):
    dates=pd.date_range(start_date,end_date) 
    df=pd.DataFrame(index=dates)
    df_temp=pd.read_csv('/home/furqan/Desktop/python_data/{}.csv'.format(str(symbol)),usecols=['Date','Close'],
                            parse_dates=True,index_col='Date',na_values=['nan'])
    df_temp = df_temp.rename(columns={'Close': symbol})
    df=df.join(df_temp)
    df=df.fillna(method='ffill')
    df=df.fillna(method='bfill')
    return df

for symbol in symbols: 
    df=data(symbol)
    pass
print(df)
```

When I run the above code it overwrites the column with the new symbol instead of making an other column within the DataFrame.

If I want to it to make new column for a each new symbol within the DataFrame, how can I achieve that without using any for loop within the function.

Expected outoput:

```
              KEL   PAEL
2016-05-01   7.07  61.74
2016-05-02   7.07  61.74
2016-05-03   7.21  62.19
2016-05-04   7.21  62.72
2016-05-05   7.20  64.24
2016-05-06   7.17  63.88
2016-05-07   7.17  63.88
2016-05-08   7.17  63.88
2016-05-09   7.25  64.12
2016-05-10   7.28  65.59
2016-05-11   7.43  65.78
```

Output I got:

```
             PAEL
2016-05-01  61.74
2016-05-02  61.74
2016-05-03  62.19
2016-05-04  62.72
2016-05-05  64.24
2016-05-06  63.88
2016-05-07  63.88
2016-05-08  63.88
2016-05-09  64.12
2016-05-10  65.59
2016-05-11  65.78
```

Comment: In your loop, you are overwriting you df by doing df=data(symbol). You should try something like df[symbol] = data(symbol) to add a new column

Comment: @A-Za-z It results in an error: NameError: name 'df' is not defined

Comment: @FurqanHashim but you still have to create the dataframe object before using it, that's what the python error is telling you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is very similar to this one : https://stackoverflow.com/a/42591863/3027854

The mistake you are making as pointed out by @A-Za-z is `df=data(symbol)` you are overwriting your dataframe so you loose the data for `KEL` and only `PAEL` remains.

Basically you need to preserve the dataframes returned by `data(symbol)` method. and late merge them.

Example:

```
symbols=['one', 'two']
start_date = '2016-05-01'
end_date = '2017-03-02'
allocation = 50000


def data(symbol):
    dates=pd.date_range(start_date, end_date) 
    df=pd.DataFrame(index=dates)
    df_temp=pd.read_csv('{}.csv'.format(str(symbol)),usecols=['Date','Close'],
                            parse_dates=True,index_col='Date',na_values=['nan'])
    df_temp = df_temp.rename(columns={'Close': symbol})
    df = df.join(df_temp)
    df = df.fillna(method='ffill')
    df = df.fillna(method='bfill')
    return df

all_dataframes = []
for symbol in symbols: 
    all_dataframes.append(data(symbol))

df = pd.concat(all_dataframes, axis=1)
```

output:

```
          one   two
2016-05-01  b   f
2016-05-02  d   f
2016-05-03  d   h
2016-05-04  d   h
```

one.csv:

```
Date,Close
2016-05-01,b
2016-05-02,d
```

two.csv:

```
Date,Close
2016-05-01,f
2016-05-03,h
```

These 4 lines should do the trick for you:

```
all_dataframes = []
    for symbol in symbols: 
        all_dataframes.append(data(symbol))

    df = pd.concat(all_dataframes, axis=1)
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks @Vikash Singh