# Get file created date - add to dataframes column on read_csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas, operating-system

I need to pull many (hundreds) CSV's into a pandas dataframe. I need to a add the date the file was created in a column upon read in to the pandas dataframe for each CSV file. I can obtain the date of creation for a CSV file using this call:

```
time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y', time.gmtime(os.path.getmtime('/path/file.csv')))
```

As an fyi, this is the command I am using to read in the CSVs:

```
path1 = r'/path/'
all_files_standings = glob.glob(path1 + '/*.csv')
standings = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f, low_memory=False, usecols=[7, 8, 9]) for f in standings))
```

I tried running this call (which worked):

```
dt_gm = [time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y', time.gmtime(os.path.getmtime('/path/file.csv')))]
```

So then I tried expanding it:

```
dt_gm = [time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y', time.gmtime(os.path.getmtime(f) for f in all_files_standings))]
```

and I get this error:

> TypeError: an integer is required (got type generator)

How can I resolve this?

Comment: do you want to read the csvs into dataframe by column (bad idea) or rows(better idea)?

Comment: i wasn't aware of a difference...

Comment: if you add columns it will look like `f1_c1,f1_c2,f2_c1,f2_c2,...` where as if you add rows it would be like `c1,c2` and rows would have values by files. first file1 rows then file2 rows, and so on.

Comment: ok, yes.  I am adding them in by rows

Comment: I have added an answer. See if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

if the different files have the same columns and you would like to append different files into rows.

```
import pandas as pd
import time
import os

# lis of files you want to read
files = ['one.csv', 'two.csv']

column_names = ['c_1', 'c_2', 'c_3']

all_dataframes = []
for file_name in files:
    df_temp = pd.read_csv(file_name, delimiter=',', header=None)
    df_temp.columns = column_names
    df_temp['creation_time'] = time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y', time.gmtime(os.path.getmtime(file_name)))
    df_temp['file_name'] = file_name
    all_dataframes.append(df_temp)

df = pd.concat(all_dataframes, axis=0, ignore_index=True)

df
```

output:

[image]

if you want to append the different files by columns:

```
all_dataframes = []
for idx, file_name in enumerate(files):
    df_temp = pd.read_csv(file_name, delimiter=',', header=None)
    column_prefix = 'f_' + str(idx) + '_'
    df_temp.columns = [column_prefix + c for c in column_names]
    df_temp[column_prefix + 'creation_time'] = time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y', time.gmtime(os.path.getmtime(file_name)))
    all_dataframes.append(df_temp)

pd.concat(all_dataframes, axis=1)
```

output:

[image]